# javascript createElement and setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginning to teach myself javascript. I thought I would try to make a script that embeds a youtube video when provided with a URL. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong when I create the iframe element, set the attributes, and append it as a child to the div? I'm using JSFiddle, and when I inspect the element no tag appears to have been added to the div. Thanks!

Edit: Here's my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/86W8N/2/

```
<p>Click the button to call function</p>
YoutubeURL: <input id="url" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="video_div">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var urlValue = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var videoID = urlValue.substring(urlValue.indexOf('=') + 1);

    var video = document.createElement("iframe");
    video.setAttribute(title, "Test");
    video.setAttribute(width, "440");
    video.setAttribute(height, "390");
    video.setAttribute(src, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID);
    video.setAttribute(frameborder, "0");

    var div_element = document.getElementById("video_div");

    div_element.appendChild(video);
}
</script>
```

Comment: first please provide jsfiddle url

Comment: and second - are you sure div_element is not null in your case?

Comment: third and most important - does the console show errors? :)

Comment: @lukas: `#video_div` is right there in markup in the original question, though, and we can see how `myFunction` is called, so it won't be before DOMReady. It is probably safe to assume that the target div will exist.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your code will stop executing, throwing a `title is not defined` exception at

```
video.setAttribute(title, "Test");
```

In `setAttribute(title, ...)` you're using `title` as though it was a variable named title, but that doesn't exist. You want instead to pass the *string value* `"title"`:

```
video.setAttribute('title', 'Test');
```

... and the same for the other attributes...

A few more hints since you're using JSFiddle:

- Make a habit of saving the fiddle and always provide the link together with your question
- Under "Framework & Extensions" in the left-hand panel, make sure you've set the javascript to load with "no wrap", otherwise you won't be able to call the method from your html the way you've done. (This applies when you're defining your JavaScript functions in the JavaScript panel. I see from your updated question with included fiddle link that you're currently putting it all in the HTML markup, so you won't have this issue)
- Hit F12 in your browser, and you will be able to see the actual error message that your code produces.

Answer (score 11):

You need to wrap your attributes in quotes `'` or double quotes `"`:

```
video.setAttribute('title', "Test");
video.setAttribute('width', "440");
video.setAttribute('height', "390");
video.setAttribute('src', "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID);
video.setAttribute('frameborder', "0");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YfJ4/)**

Answer (score 4):

Create a nifty reusable `attr` helper function like:

```js
const attr = (el, attr) => Object.entries(attr).forEach(([k, v]) => el.setAttribute(k, v));
```

Example:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const attr = (el, attr) => Object.entries(attr).forEach(([k, v]) => el.setAttribute(k, v));
const css = (el, styles) => Object.assign(el.style, styles);


// Example 1: Create button with properties:

const elBtn = elNew("button", {
  type: "button",
  className: "btn dropdown-toggle text-left font-weight-bolder",
  innerHTML: `<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Question`,
  style: `
    border: 2px solid currentColor;
    margin-top: 5px;
  `
});

// Example 2: Add attributes:

attr(elBtn, {
  "data-toggle": "dropdown",
  "aria-haspopup": true,
  "aria-expanded": false
});

// Example 3: Change styles:

css(elBtn, {
  color: "orange",
  fontSize: "1.2rem",
  padding: "0.2rem 0.5rem"
});

// Append element:
el("body").append(elBtn)
```

Read more:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)